# code fail when retrieving a larger amount of data from web service

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asp.net-4.0

I have a web service returning some Json stuff to my iPhone application and it works fine as long as the amount of returned data is kind of small but if I increase the amount of data that is returned the application is not able to process it. Is there a way to solve this, can't possibly be a limit of 218KB...?

This is my current code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mydomain.com/webservicesfeed")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class feedPerson : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(BufferResponse = false)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<Person> getData()
        {
            List<Person> res = new List<Person>();
                res = searchPerson("32.8762", "13.1875");
            return res;
        }
    }
```

If I call the web service throw jQuery it also fails so I guess the problem is at the web service..

This is the jQuery code I used to try it out:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
         url: "http://mydomain.com/feedPerson.asmx/getData",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             alert(data.d[0]);
         },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Fail");
         }
     });
    </script>
```

How could this be solved?

Comment: Have you put a break point in your web service? Does it get called?  How many persons does searchPerson return? Can you do a get request to the service with a web browser to see what you get back? Where does your 218k number come from?

Comment: @DarrylBraaten No breakpoint, it gets called, 100 persons is ok but 150 is not, if I visit http://mydomain.com/persons.asmx/getData through the browser it returns a xml file containing all persons (no problem with 150 persons), 218k is the size of the returned xml-file.

Comment: What's the failure? Is there an error or exception thrown by either the server or the client?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid I guess it is the server as the response is the same for both the iPhone app and jquery.  request: {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Do you see anything in the event log that would tell you what's going wrong? Or better, either have a try/catch block around your server code or attach a debugger and let it tell you what the exception is. Once you know what's going wrong you should be able to fix the issue (code or configuration).

Comment: have you try to set <customErrors mode="Off"> ?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid This actually helped me find the error: "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property" Will post the answer so that it hopefully helps someone else in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catching the error gave me the following information: "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property".

Then I found this post: [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

and by setting the following in my web.config:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

The issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx
There are limits by default.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"
    executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```